# ¿Como ingresar varios registros de un mismo dato en mi DataGridView?

Tags: c#

Los coloco en contexto. Tengo 2 `Datagridview`, el primero lo lleno con números de póliza que el usuario coloque y en el segundo muestro los datos de acuerdo a la póliza ingresada.
El código es el siguiente:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in paraactuzalizarpolizas.Rows){
PolizaBuscar = row.Cells["Poliza"].Value.ToString();
String ONCliente = "select Poliza, FechaPago, Monto,Estado,FechaTrajo,Ficha as Metodo, NumPago,Observacion from PAGOS where Poliza='"+PolizaBuscar+"'";
SqlCommand OpNumClient = new SqlCommand();
OpNumClient.Connection = MenuInicio.conexion;
OpNumClient.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OpNumClient.CommandText = ONCliente;
try
{
   Leer = OpNumClient.ExecuteReader();
   if (Leer.Read())
   {
       resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows.Add(Leer["Poliza"].ToString(),Leer["Monto"].ToString());
       Leer.Close();
   }
   else
   {
       resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows.Add("","No se encontro");
       Leer.Close();
   }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Buscar pago dice " + ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}}
```

El problema que tengo es que una Póliza puede tener varios pagos y cuando mando a consultarlos para ingresarlos en mi otro `DataGirdView` solo me muestra 1. Por ejemplo: Si mi Póliza 123456789 tiene 8 pagos ingresados en mi DB solo me llena una fila con el primero y necesito mostrar los 8 ya que después de esos 8 viene otra póliza y así sucesivamente.

[image: captura de pantalla]

Lo que me arroja es un pago de cada póliza cuando lo que quiero obtener es que me muestre primero todos los datos que hayan de la primera póliza leída y después de la segunda y así sucesivamente...

Comment: y donde estas cargando esos pagos?

Comment: Menciono que en el segundo muestro los resultados en el otro DGV. actualizare mi pregunta con una imagen visual

Comment: si, pero el codigo que muestras es para cargar cual dgv?

Comment: ah ya entendi...

Comment: el foreach lee el primer datagridview y adentro del foreach estoy cargando los datos al segundo datagridview

Comment: igual es una forma muy confusa y cuando lo arregles se va a entender menos.. deberias mostrar los datos de las polizas que seleccionas.. no de todas... pero ahora te cuento tu problema

Comment: habia pensado hacerlo de esa manera ya que es muchisimo mas sencillo... pero es que los datos arrojados se pueden exportar a Excel aunque veo que el boton no lo hago visible jaja.

Comment: ojala no tengas 150 polizas con 40 pagos.. porque ni a excel ni a ningun lado te va a servir exportarlos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a ver los problemas linea por linea

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in paraactuzalizarpolizas.Rows){
```

Porque haces esto, si tuvieras 20 polizas con 20 pagos cada una vas a mostrar 400 lineas, y no se va a saber de que pago es cada una.. deberias mostrar solo de la seleccionada.. pero bue.. sigamos

```
PolizaBuscar = row.Cells["Poliza"].Value.ToString();
String ONCliente = "select Poliza, FechaPago, Monto,Estado,FechaTrajo,Ficha as Metodo, NumPago,Observacion from PAGOS where Poliza='"+PolizaBuscar+"'";
```

Porque traes tantos campos en tu select, si solo usas dos? trae solo lo que necesites

```
...
try
{
    Leer = OpNumClient.ExecuteReader();
```

Perfecto, ejecutas un reader.. ahora tenes que recorrerlo con un while, porque vienen muchas filas ;)

```
if (Leer.Read())
{
    resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows.Add(Leer["Poliza"].ToString(),Leer["Monto"].ToString());
    Leer.Close();
}
```

Y eh ahi el problema.. solamente lees la primer fila, y luego cerrar el reader...

mejor, leer el reader asi:

```
while (Leer.Read())
{
    resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows.Add(Leer["Poliza"].ToString(),Leer["Monto"].ToString());
}
Leer.Close();
```

Ahora, para saber si habia o no datos, el reader te dice en su propiedad Count() (si no recuerdo mal) si existe por lo menos o no un dato... usalo a tu favor.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y por el regaño, si uso todos los datos que mando a llamar, se muestra en la captura solo que allí no los había puesto en la tabla. para lo que dices que no es entendible tienes razón, eso lo soluciono un poco con la parte de consulta avanzada que me colorea los pagos de la póliza que escoja o escriba en este caso. y estoy totalmente de acuerdo que explotara o se trabara si buscan 30+ pólizas, pero esto esta solo para consultar máximo 10 de 24 pagos cada una como máximo. Igualmente muchas gracias por tu respuesta la cual soluciono mi problema.